# IE8 acted weird on Ubuntu LTS server

Tags: css, ubuntu, internet-explorer-8, centos, margin

I recently faced an IE8 bug where the margin collapse b/w two horizontal elements. I solved it by replacing the margin with padding.

But the weird thing was that it was only specific to a "Ubuntu LTS server"! It was working fine in my staging site (Cent OS).

Any idea how it was only faced in that server and that server only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would need much, much more information to be answerable reliably, like a real world example.

However, I'm going to guess your staging site was on `localhost`, or some other address that IE treats as local. In that case, the ["smart defaults" kick in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx) (emphasis mine)

> A large number of line-of-business websites are Internet Explorer 7 capable today. In order to preserve compatibility, Internet Explorer 8 ships with smart defaults based on zone evaluation. In the default state, all sites on the public internet display in Internet Explorer 8 Standards mode (Compatibility View off) **and all intranet websites display in Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode (Compatibility View on).**
>
> ...
>
> If you navigate to sites on your local intranet like http://myPortal and http://sharepoint/sites/mySite, Internet Explorer 8 identifies itself with a User Agent string of ‘7’, Version Vector of ‘7’, and displays webpages that trigger standards mode in Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode. This combination allows webpages that worked correctly in Internet Explorer 7 to continue to do so in IE8.

Comment: Thanks Pekka for you quick response. I am sorry this all the information I have. Anyway it was not running on my local, no http://vijay-pc/project. I was an actual remote staging server. Oh the project was in drupal.

The client just copied everything to his server and loaded the DB dump, and taada, an IE issue. I had to go to his office, connect to the remote server and edit with "VIM". Cleared the drupal cache. Problem fixed.

Given the fact that I am a designer, you imagine it wasn't all easy for me!